# mapred-site.xml not overriding parameters from mapred-default.xml

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration

I am using Hadoop version 0.20.2 (Cloudera distribution cdh3u6) and seeing issues.  From what I understand, if I set a value in `/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml`, it should override the Hadoop default automatically.  So I set a variable as follows:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx1024m</value>
</property>
```

However, this has no effect.  Now, I know the file is being read by hadoop, because if I set the variable to final (`<final>true</final>`) then the setting **does** apply to my jobs.  However, from what I understand this should not be necessary because `mapred-site.xml` should be loaded AFTER `mapred-default.xml` so it should simply override it.

You might ask, is something else later in the chain also overriding the setting from `mapred-site.xml`?  That would be a logical conclusion but I can't find any evidence of this.  I have job configuration files that end up in `/var/log/hadoop` and handily state where their properties are loaded from.  So I get values like this:

```
<property><!--Loaded from /var/hadoop/mapred/local/jobTracker/job_201401081300_0009.xml--><name>mapred.child.java.opts</name><value>-Xmx200m</value></property>
```

The referenced job "subconfigurations" under the `/var/hadoop/mapred/local/jobTracker` are ephemeral and only exist when the job is running, however inspecting one from a running job I found the following:

```
<property><!--Loaded from mapred-default.xml--><name>mapred.child.java.opts</name><value>-Xmx200m</value></property>
```

So as the final job config eventually seems to be loaded simply from `mapred-default.xml` -- so why would the value from `mapred-site.xml` not override it?

Although setting `final` solves the problem, I want to understand what is going on in this situation, as it could indicate other issues.  Also, this generates a warning: `WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: /var/hadoop/mapred/local/jobTracker/job_201401081300_0009.xml: a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.child.java.opts;  Ignoring.`.  This warning suggests that another configuration parser further down the chain is indeed overriding the setting from `mapred-site.xml` -- but how can I find out what it is?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but after restarting the the services(hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager, hadoop-yarn-nodemanager ) it picked-up the value from mapred-site.xml